# Solr 4.3 Cloud and Pivoting

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We are trying Solr Cloud with Solr version 4.3, but pivoting doesn't seem to be working in this case.

```
 http://localhost:8995/solr/cmn/select?q=*%3A*&facet=true&facet.mincount=1&facet.pivot=source_domain,author&rows=1&wt=json&facet.limit=5
```

Am I missing something or this feature is not available on the cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [SOLR-792](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-792) & [SOLR-2894](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2894)
Pivot faceting currently only supports undistributed mode.
Distributed pivot faceting needs to be implemented.